# @media not working in different browsers

Tags: css, media-queries

I am a beginner to coding and currently making an app for a uni assignment. I am currently only using html and css until I get it right and then I will add JavaScript. The problem I am having is that my code is responsive on chrome for the set devices I need, but when I preview it in any other browser and on macs, the @media rules don't seem to be working.

This is my current css

```
body {
background-color:#F4BAAE;
background-image:url("Images/Pattern Landscape.png");
background-size:cover;      

        }

    #logo {
        background-image: url("Images/Logo.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size 400px 400px;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        background-position:top;
        position:fixed;
        margin:-10px;
    }   

    #start {
        background-image:url("Images/Start.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:fixed;
        border-radius:15px;
        background-position:bottom;
        width:600px;
        height:300px;

    }




    /* ----------- Webpages ----------- */  

    @media only screen and (min-device-width:1024px) {
        #start {
            background-size: 600px 300px;       
            top: 80%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -20%);

        }

        #logo {
            background-size:500px;
            top:80px;
        }
    } 

    /* ----------- Iphone 6 ----------- */  

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
        #start {
            background-size:180px 80px;
            width:180px;
            height:80px;
        }

        body {
            background-size:667px auto;
        }
    }

    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)and (orientation: portrait) { 
        #start {
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
        }

        #logo {
            background-size: 150px;
            top:54px;
        }
    }


    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)and (orientation: landscape) { 
        #start {
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
        }

        #logo {
            background-size:130px;
            top:40px
        }
    }




    /* ----------- Ipad ----------- */  

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        body {
            background-size:1024px auto;
        }
    }


    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        #start {
            background-size: 400px 180px;               
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
        }

        #logo {
            background-size:300px;
            top:50px
        }
    }


    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        #start {
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -90%);
            background-size: 340px 130px;

        }

        #logo {
            background-size:320px;
            top:50px;
        }

    }





    /* ----------- Galaxy S4 ----------- */

    /* Portrait and Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        #start {
            background-size:180px 80px;
            width:180px;
            height:80px;
            }

        body {
            background-size:640px auto;
           }

        }


    /* Portrait */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        #start {
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -90%);
        }

        #logo {
            background-size:150px;
            top:54px;
            left:10px;
        }




    /* Landscape */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        #start {
            top: 90%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -90%);
        }

        #logo {
            background-size:130px;
            top:40px;
        }                   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lose the 'device'  `@media (min-width: 600px) { ... }`

On another note... I applaud you're hard work, but your letting things get too complex.

```
body {
  background: red;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  background: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  background: green;
}
```

Small-screen-first... no device specific targeting... create a break when things get ugly... repeat...

(you can use 'only screen and' if you research it and think it's important)
(i'd ditch the ids for styling... use classes)

Comment: This seems to work but I have yet to try it on a mac (which I know my teacher users)

Comment: If your teacher insists that you use that code that you showed... you need to quit the class. I would suggest learning from someone else: https://www.codementor.io/sheriffderek

Comment: No its just something I found online, they arent really teaching us, its just watching some lectures blah blah but thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You have `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`, `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`, etc in the media queries. `-webkit-*` is a browser prefix and will only apply to safari/chrome. Unless you only want the media query to fire for a webkit based browser, you likely want to use the non-prefixed versions of those instead. Like `device-pixel-ratio`, `min-device-pixel-ratio`, etc.

Comment: When doing this, it doesn't apply the media rules at all

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error or something then if it's not working at all anywhere. Since those `-webkit-*` prefixed properties are in the media query, it will only work on webkit enabled browsers. Feel free to share what you did and what exactly isn't working if you want more help with it. @KianaTaylor

Comment: I basically removed the -webkit- from all media queries and was left with this   /* Portrait and Landscape */
  @media screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
   #start {
    background-size:180px 80px;
    width:180px;
    height:80px;
    }